# Populate data in dropdown not showing up in asp-net-core/c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am coming to a problem where I have a form that inside the form I have a dropdown where I am getting data from my controller(backend), but for some reason I have not populating the data on my front end. I have the same form in another .cshtml file which `EvaluationController` and I am implementing the same form in the index.cshtml file and its using HomeController. I need some help of where I have done wrong that the data is not populating on the front end? Please and thank you for your help.

here is my code:

HomeController:

```
        public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;
        private IMemoryCache _cache;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
            _cache = memoryCache;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Cache = _cache;

             return View();
        }



        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {

            return View();
        }



        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error:

> The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[MyApp.Models.Evaluation]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'MyApp.Models.Evaluation'

In your `EvaluationController` on the `Index` you return a list:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new List<Evaluation>());
}
```

It should be:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new Evaluation());
}
```

or change the Model in you **Index.cshtml** to something like `@model List<Evaluation>();`.

Comment: Correct. However, if I put the same code in my EvaluationController inside HomeController and the fix of yours will I solve my issue?

Comment: So, yeah I put the same code inside my HomeController and I get an error: `NullReferenceException: cache cannot be null`

Comment: Update your question with the exception.

Comment: never mind I added `ViewBag.Cache = _cache;`  inside `Index()` . thank you for your help.